# Are WebSockets my best option for mobile to multiple server communications?

Tags: java, mobile, websocket, client-server, mobile-application

**Overview:**

I currently have two fully functioning mobile applications that communicate with Java servers running on Windows via WebSockets. For each app, the WebSocket ServerEndpoint is running off of one AWS machine. The Java servers are ClientEndpoints running on separate private networks, and there can be multiple app users at any given time that are also ClientEndpoints.  Mobile app users from Client A need to be communicating with Java server A, mobile app users from Client B will need to be communicating with Java server B, and so on.  The ServerEndpoints keep track of Java ClientEndpoints and corresponding mobile app ClientEndpoints using Java code I've written.  I am basically maintaining an ID, Java server WebSocket session, and a `Set` of WebSocket client sessions as part of a `WebSocketEntity`.

**Question:**

Am I handling this correctly?  Everything is working as intended, but I am not sure what the best practice is for this type of communication.  I have to assume under most scenarios there is a single server that multiple users are communicating with.  Because each of our clients has their own back-end database on their own private network, it creates the need to handle things the way I currently am doing so.

Each app will always have its own ServerEndpoint whose implementation should not need to change.  I somewhat have a concern as to what happens when we continue creating more apps.  Should each app continue to have its own separate ServerEndpoint?  Are there better technologies, tools, etc. that I should be using instead to make things easier and more standardized?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Unless you're actually placing these separate servers in different networks and you need to do that for database access reasons, then you could implement this with one server where the server knows which back-end database corresponds with each connecting client socket.  So, then the single server just uses the appropriate database for each connection.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the response.  Our primary application is more of a  traditional Windows Server/Client application.  This is the reason why the servers are on different networks.  The mobile applications need to communicate with the same server and database as the Windows client.

Comment: I guess I don't have a clear understanding of the network topology, who needs to talk to who and who is where on the network so I can't really help further.  For efficiency of scale, you'd like to not need a server for every new client (that's why so much business is moving to a cloud architecture).  I was trying to explore if that is possible.  If it's not, I don't know what you're really asking here.  I don't think the situation is described well enough for someone to know enough of the constraints or requirements to suggest a better architecture.

Comment: @jfriend00 We currently have X number of established clients who own and maintain their own servers on their own private networks.  These servers run our Java server application that is connected to a back-end database.  A number of users on their network run our Java client application that connects to the Java server and interacts with the database.

We also developed mobile applications that can be run from anywhere, that also need to communicate with the same Java server mentioned above and interact with the same database

Comment: @jfriend00 The WebSocket is running on a publicly accessible AWS Server which allows communication between the mobile apps and the Java server/database running on the private network(s).

We plan and hope to move more clients to a separate cloud architecture that we have been working on, however that will take some time.

Comment: Can't tell what you're asking.  You're already working towards a cloud architecture which is probably the desired way to go.  Your current scheme works for now until you have a cloud architecture running.  Not sure what you're asking then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121386/discussion-between-tommo-and-jfriend00).